# THEN statement returning with promise/always return and consistent-return bugs

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions, twilio-api

This is the code for a google cloud function I am trying to deploy.  I'm getting a error saying that my .then() promises or inconsistent. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const twilio = require('./twilio');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.phone) {
    return res
      .status(422)
      .send({ error: 'You must provide a phone number' });
  }

  const phone = String(req.body.phone).replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

  admin
    .auth()
    .getUser(phone)
    .then(userRecord => {
      const code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8999 + 1000));

      const message = {
        body: 'Your code is ' + code,
        to: phone,
        from: '+18053167032'
      };

      const callback = (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(422).send(err);
        }

        admin
          .database()
          .ref('users/' + phone)
          .update(
            { code: code, codeValid: true },
            () => { res.send({ success: true }
          );
      };

      twilio.messages.create(message, callback);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(422).send({ error: err });
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI you can properly format code by selecting all of it and using the {} button in the editor the indent the whole thing.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show exact the error you are receiving?

Comment: I've made the code readable, in part by breaking out the arguments to `twilio.messages.create`.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, it is hard your indentation blocks using the curly braces exactly, and in response to @hanoldaa's mention of arrow functions, it is quite important to be able to trace exactly where the userRecord => function will end. If it says your .then promises are inconsistent, then I would assume you are either calling .then on non-promise objects, or you are not handling unresolved Promises.

Javascript.info has a great suggestion on a global handling of unresolved promises, using:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
  // the event object has two special properties:
  alert(event.promise); // [object Promise] - the promise that generated the error
  alert(event.reason); // Error: Whoops! - the unhandled error object
});

new Promise(function() {
  throw new Error("Whoops!");
}); // no catch to handle the error
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

At the end, you do

```
.catch((err) => {
  res.status(422).send({ error: err });
});
```

but `err` shouldn't be wrapped in parenthesis. Use

```
.catch(err => {
  res.status(422).send({ error: err });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to resolve part of the error, however I am still having an issue with everything before that starting with the '.then(userRecord => ...'  Any other suggestions on how to resolve that?

Comment: Instead of an arrow function, you could try `.then(function(userRecord) {` with the same in the catch.

Comment: still no improvement.  also creates a warning stating the preference of arrow callbacks

Comment: Can you explain why the `()` *"should"* be removed...?

Comment: Hmm, not sure on the error then. Could you post the full error with stacktrace? Maybe a screenshot. My assumption was that the inconsistency was complaining about declaring the arrow functions differently, but clearly that's not the case. With single parameters, the `()` is optional.